# WordPress website hides all <iframe> elements on homepage

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, iframe

I'm working on a website that was created using WordPress. WordPress (or possibly a plugin, theme, or something else) is inserting the following CSS into the homepage:

```
<style type="text/css"> iframe { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; } </style>
```

The above code is included as part of the original HTTP response received after a request for the homepage (I confirmed this using curl from my terminal).

I imagine the above code is part of a mechanism either to:

- display the other content on the page as fast as possible and only display the  elements after everything else has been displayed; or
- display the  elements only after dynamically setting their width, height, position, etc.

In Safari v9.1, the  elements eventually get displayed. However, Firefox v47.0.1 failed to ever display the  elements.

I can't provide a link to the actual website for privacy reasons.

Does anyone know what's going on? If not, does anyone have any suggestions about how I can find the Javascript code that is supposed to unhide the  elements?

Comment: try to execute your browser without any plugin and then if the problem persist go in the configuration to see if its not a blocking paramater...

Comment: You've been hacked. Trojans hide iframes so their injections are less obvious. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hidden-iframes Install the Securi plugin and work through their wizards. You may need to restore a backup or build a fresh site and import your database.